# How to Group Array by Property and Reindex Result

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to group items an array of items by a property and then reindex the result starting from `0`.

The following function returns a grouped set of items.

```
groupItemBy(array, property) {
  let hash = {},
  props = property.split('.');
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      let key = props.reduce( (acc, prop) => {
        return acc && acc[prop];
      }, array[i]);
      if (!hash[key]) hash[key] = [];
        hash[key].push(array[i]);
      }
      return hash;
}
```

The result is an array of arrays, and something like:

```
[{
  "1193312":[
    {
      "description":"Item 1",
      "number": "1193312"
    }
  ],
  "1193314":[
    {
      "itemDesc":"Item 2"},
      "number": "1193314"
    {
      "description":"Item 3",
      "number": "1193314"
    }
  ],
  etc...
}]
```

From here I'd like to map `1193312` to `0`, and `1193314` to `1`, etc.

I tried `.filter(val => val)` on the result, but that seemed to have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an intermediate key replacement:

```
function groupItemBy(array, property) {
  let hash = {}
  let props = property.split('.')
  let keys = []

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let key = props.reduce((acc, prop) => {
      return acc && acc[prop];
    }, array[i]);
    let subst = keys.indexOf(key)
    if (subst === -1) {
        keys.push(key)
        subst = keys.length - 1
    }
    if (!hash[subst]) hash[subst] = [];
    hash[subst].push(array[i]);
  }
  return hash;
}
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/05t9141p/ ]

Answer (score 2):

You could use `map` for the array part, and `Object.values` and reduce for the renumber part.

```js
const data = [{
  "1193312":[
    {
      "time":"2018-02-20",
      "description":"Item 1",
      "number": "1193312"
    }
  ],
  "1193314":[
    {
      "time":"2018-02-21",
      "itemDesc":"Item 2",
      "number": "1193314"
    },{
      "time":"2018-02-21",
      "description":"Item 3",
      "number": "1193314"
    }
  ]
}];

const renumbered =
  data.map((m) => Object.values(m).reduce((a,v,ix) => (a[ix] = v, a), {}));
  
console.log(renumbered);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [{
  "1193312":[
    {
      "description":"Item 1",
      "number": "1193312"
    }
  ],
  "1193314":[
    {
      "itemDesc":"Item 2",
      "number": "1193314"},
    {
      "description":"Item 3",
      "number": "1193314"
    }
  ]
}]
var newData = Object.keys(data[0]).map(function(key,index){
var newObj={};
newObj[index] = data[0][key];
return newObj;
});
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `ES6`:

```js
var arr = [{
  "1193312":[
    {
      "time":"2018-02-20",
      "description":"Item 1"
    }
  ],
  "1193314":[
    {
      "time":"2018-02-21",
      "itemDesc":"Item 2"}, 
    {
      "time":"2018-02-21",
      "description":"Item 3"
    }
  ]
}];
var data = arr[0];
var res = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value}));
console.log(res);
```